# Hackerrank apples and oranges question test cases fail on submit in swift

Tags: swift

The detail of question is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange/problem

My code passed sample test cases when I click on Run button but when I click on submit button all test cases fail. My code is given below:

```
func countApplesAndOranges(s: Int, t: Int, a: Int, b: Int, apples: [Int], oranges: [Int]) -> Void {

  var appless = [Int]()
  var orangess = [Int]()

  appless = apples.map{a + $0}
  orangess = oranges.map{b + $0}
  appless = appless.filter{$0 >= s && $0 <= t}
  orangess = orangess.filter{$0 >= s && $0 <= t}

  print(appless.count)
  print(orangess.count)

}

countApplesAndOranges(s: 7, t: 11, a: 5, b: 15, apples: [-2,2,1], oranges: [5,-6])
```

If someone knows what is the issue then please let me know.

Comment: Fails how, please explain the issue better and add some examples where the code fails? This is a site for programming questions and not a support site for hackerrank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test cases fail because your code does not fulfil all the requirements of the question. Try to read question carefully.
For me the code given below passed all the test cases on submit:

```
import Foundation;

// Enter your code here

let hitRange = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }
let treePoints = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }
let applesOranges = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }
let apples = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }
let oranges = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map{ Int($0)! }


var appleInRange = 0
var orangeInRange = 0

for apple in apples {
   let result = treePoints[0] + apple
   switch result {
      case hitRange[0]...hitRange[1]:
          appleInRange += 1
      default:
          continue
   }
}

for orange in oranges {
    let result = treePoints[1] + orange
    switch result {
           case hitRange[0]...hitRange[1]:
                orangeInRange += 1
           default:
              continue
    }
}

print(appleInRange)
print(orangeInRange)
```

Comment: Don't just give the solution, it completely defeats the purpose of the exercise.